# Eloquent query that queries based on a relationship with a relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to describe my problem in the title was difficult.  What I mean is this.  I have 3 tables.  Job, Diary, Document.
Each diary entry has a belongsTo relationship with Job.  Each Document has a belongsTo relationship with Diary.

How can I query Documents so it returns all the documents belonging to a single job.

Document->diary_id references Diary->id - Diary->job_number_id references Job->id

Both these individual relationships are set up and work.

I have tried different queries with no success.

Any help appreciated.
Regards
Finchy70

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`HasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship:

```php
public function documents() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Document::class, Diary::class, 'job_number_id');
}

$documents = $job->documents()->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am away from my Mac at the moment but will try this in the morning and feed back.  Looks good though.

Comment: Works like a dream.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have continued to research and try different eloquent queries and have found one that works.
Not sure how economical it is but it does work.

```
$documents = $job->diary()
        ->with('job')
        ->join('documents', 'diary_id', '=', 'diaries.id')
        ->select(['documents.*'])
        ->paginate(15);
```

If anyone has a better solution please share.